# Azure AD B2C Application Change in Manifest shows Internal Server Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have recently Registered a Keycloak Application on my Azure AD B2C tenant, one of my colleagues accidentally deleted the registration, so i have restored the application on the Azure portal, Later i tried changing the Redirection URI, but the Azure portal doesn't allow me to do so and shows the below error

"Failed to update KeyCloak application. Error detail: Encountered an internal server error."

I have tried to change the same in the Manifest and tried to upload file, even it shows the same error.

Did my application restore made any difference here, if it was so please suggest me some check points to solve this.
Note : The other applications in this tenant allow me to do same changes, I have issue only with this application registration.

Comment: Show what you did to restore the object. Does both the App object and ServicePrincial object exist?

Comment: On the power shell i used ,,Get-AzureAdDeletedApplication" and later after having the list of applications with object ids and app ids i have taken the object id and with Restore-AzureADDeletedApplication -ObjectId XXXX-581dbf7b3fe4 and restored the application

Comment: Raised an [github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/65825) for this and you can track the progress

Answer (score 0):

A bug has been filed and the product team is working on it. In the mean time for the work around  **Please re-create another app if possible.**

You could also try to change "SignInAudience" to "AzureADMultipleOrgs" (if it works) - than you'll be able to modify reply urls and switch "SignInAudience" back.